# How can I wrap an async call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to have three functions that do something like this:

```
function getuser1(){
  var user = b();
  //do some stuff to user
  return user;
}

function getuser2(){
  var user = asyncfinduser();
  //do some different stuff to user
  return user;
}

function asyncfinduser(){
  userDB.find( { /* some criteria */ }, function (error, user) {
    //return found user to functions above
    return user;
  });
)
```

The above is obviously not going to work so how can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Rather than returning the user from your async function to your other functions, you should pass the other functions to the async function as callbacks.

Comment: As @jahroy suggests use callbacks, or return a `promise` from your `asyncfinduser` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot [`return` synchronously from async callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572), you will need to use callbacks:

```
function getuser1(callback) {
  asyncfinduser(function(error, user) {
    if (error) return callback(error);
    //do some stuff to user
    callback(null, user);
  });
}

function getuser2(callback) {
  asyncfinduser(function(error, user) {
    if (error) return callback(error);
    //do some different stuff to user
    callback(null, user);
  });
}

function asyncfinduser(callback) {
  userDB.find( { /* some criteria */ }, function (error, user) {
    if (error) return callback(error);
    //return found user to functions above
    callback(null, user);
  });
}
```

However, you might be able to apply the [promise pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572):

```
var Promise = …; // some library

function getuser1() {
  return asyncfinduser().then(function(user) {
    //do some stuff to user
    return user;
  });
}

function getuser2() {
  return asyncfinduser().then(function(user) {
    //do some different stuff to user
    return user;
  });
}

function asyncfinduser() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    userDB.find( { /* some criteria */ }, function (error, user) {
    if (error) reject(error);
    else resolve(user); //return found user to functions above
  });
}
```